# Linking SSMS and ACCESS

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I'm trying to create an interactive link between SQL Server Management Studio and ACCESS.<>
SSMS versions:
Server Management Studio    15.0.18410.0 (or v18.11.1)
SQL Server Management Objects (SMO) 16.100.47008.0+9f71e8549924d85d66afcca2b9f45a33061faa1b
Microsoft Analysis Services Client Tools    15.0.19750.0
Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC) 10.0.19041.1
Microsoft MSXML 3.0 6.0 SQL
Microsoft .NET Framework    4.0.30319.42000
Operating System    10.0.19044

Provider: Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0

If I turn on "Allow inprocess", I get this error when creating the link:

> Failed to retrieve data for this request. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc)
> For help, click: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&LinkId=20476

---

> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
> An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)

---

> The OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0" for linked server "SQL 2" reported an error. Access denied.
> Cannot obtain the required interface ("IID_IDBSchemaRowset") from OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0" for linked server "SQL 2". (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 7399)
> For help, click: https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/mssqlserver-7399-database-engine-error*

---

If I turn off "Allow inprocess", I can create the link, but get this error when I try to expand System Tables:

> Server Management Studio

---

> The linked server has been created but failed a connection test. Do you want to keep the linked server?

---

> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
> An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)

---

> Cannot create an instance of OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0" for linked server "SQL TEST ALLOW". (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 7302)
> For help, click: https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/mssqlserver-7302-database-engine-error*

Comment: You don't; SSMS is just an IDE like application, you can't use it to connec to an Access database, and Access connecting to SSMS doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Is your real question that you want to create a linked server in SQL Server to talk to an Access database?

Comment: @Conor -- yes, I'm trying to have an ACCESS front-end use a SQL Server back-end.  I can create a table but changes in one app don't appear in the other.  I tried Microsoft SQL Server Migration Assistant for Access and SQL Server 2019 Import and Export Data but neither worked.

Comment: You don't want to use SSMS for this - you want to create a linked table in Access and use an ODBC connection to talk to SQL Server as a back-end.  All of this is in Access, not SQL's tools.